# What do I substitute for charAt when dealing with ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, charat

This is my first assignment with ArrayLists, and I am just now learning that you cannot use charAt. I do not know how to proceed in this assignment. The purpose of the program is to print out an array that gives the average for each vowel. E.g., an array of [cheese, cheese, cheese] would be [0, 3, 0, 0, 0]. I am not concerned with how to finish the program. Just the charAt problem. Is there another method that is usually substituted for this for ArrayLists, and if not, will someone please walk me through a solution? I am just going to post the part of my code I'm talking about. If anyone wants me to post more, let me know.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ArrayListVowels {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

    ArrayList<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>();

    vowels.add("chocolate");
    vowels.add("pudding");
    vowels.add("elephants");


    System.out.println(vowels);
    System.out.println("Avg number of vowel characters: " + averageVowels(vowels));


}


public static int[] averageVowels(ArrayList<String> vowels) {

    int [] vowelInt = new int [5];

    for (int i = 0; i<vowels.size(); i++) {
        char letter = vowels.charAt(i);
        if(letter=='a') {
            vowelInt[0]++;
        } else if (letter == 'e') {
            vowelInt[1]++;
        } else if (letter == 'i') {
            vowelInt[2]++;
        } else if (letter == 'o') {
            vowelInt[3]++;
        } else if (letter == 'u') {
            vowelInt[4]++;
        }

    }

    return vowelInt;
}
```

so I understand that vowels.get(0) will get chocolate, but if I wanted to get 'o' I would have to do a loop-within a loop. I was thinking on that track before, but how can you do that, when you aren't really defining the strings at all? You are just "adding" them. I think it would be different if it was like String x = "chocolate", because then you could do something like charAt there. This is why I'm confused I suppose. Here is how I was working on the loop, but I'm really not sure if I'm on the right track.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<vowels.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<[0].length; j++) { //I totally know that's wrong
        char letter = charAt(i);
```

Is this sort of what you were talking about?

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for your help. I understand the subject much better now. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  int [] vowelInt = new int [5];

for (int i = 0; i<vowels.size(); i++) {
    String word =(String) vowels.get(i);//try like this
char letter=word.charAt(0);   //return method to a dynamic array.    
if(letter=='a') {
        vowelInt[0]++;
    } else if (letter == 'e') {
        vowelInt[1]++;
    } else if (letter == 'i') {
        vowelInt[2]++;
    } else if (letter == 'o') {
        vowelInt[3]++;
    } else if (letter == 'u') {
        vowelInt[4]++;
    }
```

Comment: This will only look at the first letter in each word.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the i'th element of a `List` with `get(i)`.

In this case you need further updates though.  If `vowels` is `["ham", "cheese", "bread"]` then `get(0)` will return the `String` "ham", the 0th element of `vowels`.  If you want to look at each letter in "ham" then you need to do something further, like using another loop inside the first and `charAt` to look at each letter in the string.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried that, and received a compiler error stating:

ArrayListVowels.java:39: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: char
   char letter = vowels.get(i);
                           ^
1 error

Comment: Right, because your `List` is of `String`s not `char`s.  What does `vowels` actually contain?

Comment: Updated answer with more information.  Yes it would work (or you'd get a different error at least) if it were an arraylist of chars but that's not what you have.